# Issue with heavy workload in EMR-Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a heavy workload in EMR using spark. My data size is more than 200 TB. I am doing transformations like - joins,groupby, sort etc with other dataframes which also is in billions

I am using the instances `Primary - r6g.8xlarge`
`Core    - r6g.12xlarge` to spin up emr and using dynamic allocation is turn on by default(I believe).

BUt still I am getting errors like -

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC
Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you provide any details as to the underlying data store,, partitioning code, skew etc.?  it's not really clear what the issue would be  other than your queries can't easily complete.

Comment: Adding to @Chris points, is it possible to add the code that is usually hanging (don't need to be real code, can be just the general idea)? The joins are being performed on top of multiple tables that are bigger than 200TB or some of them are smaller tables that could be broadcasted to the executors? Is there way for you to get the stats of data shuffling?

Comment: This kind of messages is result, not cause. Instances disconnect when job fails. 
Transformations like join and grouping take more memory and even disk space due to shuffle write.

You can check the Spark history server in the EMR cluster.